# Instagram Bot with nodejs and puppeteer

Tags: node.js, bots, puppeteer, instagram

I wrote a bot to login in instagram with nodejs and puppeteer. but when I click on login this error will appear : CSRF token missing or incorrect, How can I resolve it ?

```
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 10066.0.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
    
    // Load Instagram
    await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/',{waitUntil:'networkidle2'});
    await page.waitForSelector(cnf.username_field, {timeout: 100000});

    await page.screenshot({ path: `screenshots/1.jpeg` }); 

    // Login
    await page.click(cnf.username_field);
    await page.keyboard.type(cnf.username);
    await page.click(cnf.password_field);
    await page.keyboard.type(cnf.password);

    await page.screenshot({ path: `screenshots/2.jpeg` });

    
    await page.click(cnf.login_button);  

    browser.close();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxEkC.png)

Comment: also post the "cnf" part

Comment: {
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
"selectors": {
      "home_to_login_button": "._acan button",
      "username_field": "input[type=\"text\"]",
      "password_field": "input[type=\"password\"]",
      "login_button": "button[type=\"submit\"]",
}
}